# Unknown child component when the parent component is functional

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-functional-component

I have a parent component that contains 2 child components and uses the Vue 2 composition API plugin.
It throws the error "[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly?" **only** when the component is functional; it works with a stateful component.
`<over-view>` is selected because the prop isSearching is false; but it is the same problem for SearchView if the condition is reverted (`v-if="!props.isSearching"`).

Both children are stateful components.

```html
<template functional>
  <main :id="id">
    <search-view v-if="props.isSearching"/>

    <over-view v-else />
  </main>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api';
import SearchView from '@/components/SearchView.vue';
import OverView from '@/components/OverView.vue';

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    SearchView,
    OverView
  },
  props: {
    isSearching: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    },
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    return {
      emit,
      props
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried or will consider using v-show instead of v-if ?

Comment: @KarlL v-show will render both components; and it will trigger the whole searching module. I don't want this behavior as it will add more load at startup time.

Comment: can you add `v-if` for `main` and then rendered inner custom component
`<div :id="id">
  <main v-if="props.isSearching">
    <search-view />
  </main>
  <main v-else>
    <over-view />
  </main>
</div>`

Comment: @Lyokolux, how about using dynamic components ?